# Why doesn't a max-heap have a decrease-key operation, and a min-heap a increase-key operation?

Tags: data-structures, heap

The operation of increase-key or decrease-key is for updating a key within a max- or min-heap, respectively.

Why doesn't a max-heap have a decrease-key operation, and a min-heap a increase-key operation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This have been discussed before [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10203/increase-key-and-decrease-key-in-a-binary-min-heap). To sum up, these operations can easily be implemented in `O(log(n))` but usually aren't provided because they have little interest from a pure algorithmic perspective.

On the contrary, decrease-key on a min heap have an existing `O(1)` implementation in a Fibonacci Heap and has an application, for example in a Dijkstra path-finding.